# Functors in List Reversal Natural Transformation

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, type-theory

A common example of a natural transformation as it relates to CS/programming languages is list reversal. `List` is a functor from `Set -> Set` where some set `S` is mapped to the set `List(S)` of all finite lists with elements drawn from `S`, and `f: S -> T` is mapped to `List(f): List(S) -> List(T)` which applies `f` to each item in an element of `List(S)`. It is often then stated that list reversal `rev` (e.g., `rev([1, 2, 3]) = [3, 2, 1])`) is a natural transformation, where the unit is defined as `rev_S` for each set type `S`. This is because `rev_T ∘ List(f) = List(f) ∘ rev_S` (i.e., order doesn't matter when it comes to mapping over a list and reversing it). This equality (i.e., the commuting square and definition of the unit) all makes sense to me.

However, here's my confusion: a natural transformation is defined as a mapping from one functor to another. I understand the definition of `List` as a functor, but I don't understand what the second functor is in this case. So, my question boils down the the following: typically, for two categories `C` and `D` and two functors `F, G: C -> D`, a natural transformation `n: F => G` is understood as mapping the functor `F` to `G`. What are the types for the natural transformation `rev`? Is it `rev`: `List => List`? In other words, is it a mapping from the `List` functor to itself? If so, can somebody help me wrap my head around that? What is then the purpose of such a natural transformation? To show some preservation in the original functor?

Thank you to anyone who can provide some intuition on this!

Comment: The second functor is also List.  The first use I'd make of this example is to show that a natural transformation from a functor to itself need not be just the identity.